# VSTS Continuous Integration: NuGet package are missing on this computer

Tags: msbuild, nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package-restore, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am using Visual Studio 2015, i have a solution  with 2 different web applications. There exists One Solution and two projects under it. The files related to nuget are distributed as:

1. Packages Folder is in the Solution Directory
2. Package.config in each project directory

There is no nuget folder: nuget.config and nuget.exe in my solution.

My Project build and run fine in Visual Studio, but I am facing a problem when using VSTS Continuous Integration with Build Solution Step (which use a  build definition that maps to one project) it gives:

```html
This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use 
NuGet Package Restore to download them. For more information, see  The missing file is 
..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props.
```

This is MyProject.csproj file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{BBD26A49-D1F4-4391-9D60-2469433DEE0D}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>AdminUI</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>AdminUI</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.5.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <MvcBuildViews>false</MvcBuildViews>
    <UseIISExpress>true</UseIISExpress>
    <IISExpressSSLPort />
    <IISExpressAnonymousAuthentication />
    <IISExpressWindowsAuthentication />
    <IISExpressUseClassicPipelineMode />
    <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
    <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
```

I noticed that it only tries to import the package that generated the error, but it doesn't explicitly import other packages, but it include them as references:

```html
<Reference Include="WebGrease">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\WebGrease.1.5.2\lib\WebGrease.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Antlr3.Runtime">
      <Private>True</Private>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Antlr.3.4.1.9004\lib\Antlr3.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

This also the end of the **myProject.csproj** file:

```html
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" />
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props'))" />
  </Target>
```

I am wondering why it gives this error, *taking into consideration that this package is already installed in the previous step "Nugget Install"*. Why it can't find it? i have spent a lot of time on this issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this worked for me:

Adding the mapping (repository configuration) to the packages folder in the solution

> Repository Configuration

[image]

> Nuget Install Config

[image]

Then, it worked like a charm.

Comment: I encounter the same problem but am not able to find Repository Tab.

Answer (score 1):

Before you add the build task, you can add nuget install or restore task. This will restore/install the nuget packages on the build agent.

Comment: I  have tried both, but generating different errors. This error happens when i specify the install, the "Path to solution" for this task is pointing to the "packages.config" in the project directory.

Comment: You can best add **/*.sln in the 'Path to solution or packages.config' and leave the 'Path to NuGet.config' empty.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the `Package.config` file you've mentioned exists in source control.

It may be that everything builds successfully on your machine because `Package.config` exists there but not in source control for when the continuous integration agent tries to download and build the project.